# List in class is null even though I made an instance of the class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to access the list `personal` from some functions in the main program but I keep getting that it's not an instance of...

The class code:

```
[Serializable()]
class FaktNr
{
    public int lopnummer;
    public int year;

    public List<string> personal = new List<string>();

    public FaktNr()
    {
        personal = new List<string>();

    }
}
```

The form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    internal FaktNr faktNr = new FaktNr(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void laggTillPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            faktNr.personal.Add(ComboBox1.Text);
    }
```

Code is shortened here but it shows the essentials. Nullreferenceexception occurs in function `laggTillPerson_Click`.

I want to add that its not the ComboBox that is the problem since i already tried this:
 faktNr.personal.Add("uhiouh");

Comment: Have you ran your code in debug mode to check what is null?

Comment: maybe it nok `FaktNr` but `ComboBox1` that is null

Comment: Is it all the form? Is it possible that the `faktNr` instance is replaced with another deserialized object somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Thanks all for the effort. Sina Iravanian was right. I had an object that was deserialized and did not contain an instance of the list. Really silly mistake! Thanks again– user2054229

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception on `ComboBox1.Text`, your `ComboBox1` could be null,  not your list `personal`, Try replacing your code with:

```
faktNr.personal.Add("test string");
```

and see if you still get the exception.

You are accessing the `Text` property of the Combobox, instead you may use [ComboBox.SelectedText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx)

Or you can check for null in your event:

```
private void laggTillPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(ComboBox1 != null)
          faktNr.personal.Add(ComboBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Why testing that the `Text` property is not null? Adding `null` to a list of string won't throw any exception.

Comment: @ken2k, I meant check for `ComboBox1` being null :), updated my answer

Comment: No thats (unfortunately) not the problem. I should ofc have included that i already tried this:

Comment: Thanks all for the effort. Sina Iravanian was right. I had an object that was deserialized and did not contain an instance of the list. Really silly mistake!